# javascript - Can do something that interacting between 2 window?

Tags: javascript

example Flickr.com

When i go to and login

-a new popup window

- fill information & login
- close popup, refresh first window

How to interacting 2 window like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before the window closes an action is called

```
window.opener.reload();
```

or

```
window.opener.refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

call this function

```
     function closeWindow() {

        if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
           window.opener.location.reload();

        } 
        window.close();
     }
```

[location.reload()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)